# connecting to mysql database failing

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

**Most recent problem is "Third Error" listed below.**

I am working on an application in java that needs to connect to a database. Below is the code that i am using to attempt to connect to the database. The port is 3306 and i have the database set up on a machine here at my house on the network. For the ip address i am just using my external ip address to the world. The username and password were replaced for my protection. In my /etc/mysql/my.cnf, "bind_address" is commented out.

I have tried several things and can not seem to get this to work. This is my first time using JDBC... thanks for any help! Let me know if you need more information.

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        System.out.println("before connection");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ip-address/mjla_db", "username", "password");
        System.out.println("connection established");
```

Here is the error that i keep getting:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at school.cs321.mjla.MJLA.main(MJLA.java:30)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:294)
    ... 15 more
```

---

**Second Error**
After changing ip address to the internal ip address of the server.

```
java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '192.168.1.102' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1128)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2336)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at school.cs321.mjla.MJLA.main(MJLA.java:30)
```

---

**Third error**
When trying to access the database with the external ip address on an external network, i get the same error that i had initially.

I am using the "%" wild card for the Host of the username i am using for the application to authenticate to the database.

Comment: Check any firewall s, check to make sure the *external* IP is actually available internally.

Comment: use localhost. I do not think mysql default config allows external connections. I suspect that if you use the external ip, there is a roundtrip (or maybe your computer's instance cannot be found from localhost like this).

Comment: @DaveNewton After using my internal ip address for my server i get the second error that is listed in the OP.

Comment: I figured it out, it was not liking that i was using md5 for the password... any way to fix that so i can use md5 instead of "PASSWORD"?

Comment: Sounds more like your user wasn't configured in MySQL to allow arbitrary (or specified) hosts.

Comment: Now that i am not on my network, using the external ip address to connect to the database is not working... what can i do to fix this?

Comment: It sounds like you have not configured the users and hosts correctly in your mysql database.  I think one of the default entries provides a generic local access.  This entry will be used first before a specific entry for a local user.  I.e. does the generic entry use PASSWORD?  But what you want to use is the user that has md5 as the password.  Also you will not be able to connect remotely unless you enable this in both the hosts and user tables correctly.  Also see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html for more general information.

Comment: You probably need to do something like <code>grant all on database_name.* to user_name@'ip_address_of_user' identified by 'password';</code>  To enable your remote connection.

Comment: I have something like that, but i put "%" for ip address so that it does not matter what ip address that user is using and it is still not working.

Comment: This is still not working, anyone have information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dave Newton: I was making the assumption that my firewall still had the port open for mysql, because i just got through working on a project where i did the same thing. However, i must have closed it a couple months ago. I checked a few minutes ago and it was disabled. So, i enabled and it is working fine now. Not sure why it had been closed...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the IP address in `getConnection` is correct? Can you try with

```
telnet youserver 3306
```

to see if there is a connection problem? Is there a firewall on the server?

Comment: After i changed ip address to the internal address of my server i got the following "second error" in the original post. Have any ideas?

Comment: When doing the telnet command above i get "is not allowed to connect to this mysql serverconnection closed by foreign host."

Comment: I figured it out, it was not liking that i was using md5 for the password... any way to fix that so i can use md5 instead of "PASSWORD"?

Comment: Now that i am not on my network, using the external ip address to connect to the database is not working... what can i do to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/student", "root", "root");
```

just try it

Comment: You may want to add some description to your answer, to help other understand it.

Comment: You are answering the question as a new user. I can see your answer in a [Review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work). And make suggestion if improvements can be made to your answer. Please don't take it personally. Basically, I'm helping you to improve your answer.